# Two of my four HDDs in my RAID10 array aren't being recognized as part of the array. How do I get them back into the array?

Tags: windows-7, raid

The short version: 
I have a Windows 7 PC with 4 x 4TB HDDs in RAID10, managed by Intel RST, which lists all of the drives as Status: Normal (and big green checks) but two of the drives aren't recognized as part of the array and the array itself is Status: Failed. Also when I check the partition types, the 2 HDDs that aren't in the array are GPT, while the 2 HDDs in the array are MBR and 'Not Applicable.' How do I get the drives back into the array? The drives are of course not accessible thorough Windows Explorer.

HDDs via Intel RST:
[image]

Extra details (i.e., how I got here):
One day suddenly, clicking on E: drive yielded a dialogue box blocking access and saying I need to format the drives. Intel RST software that managed the RAID wouldn't run, producing some non-helpful error. Re-installation attempts of the RST software were failures. Also, checking the SATA mode in the BIOS showed it was AHCI  when it should have been RAID. So I changed it to RAID. But then I couldn't boot because the bootmgr couldn't be found. So I removed the 4 drives and put them in a new and identical PC, and that's when I saw that 2 drives weren't in the array anymore.

So how can I make the RAID incorporate all four drives again? Or how can I get at the files some other way?

Answer (score -1):

I have previously had this error with a similar setup (4 drives in RAID 10 with an Intel controller).  My array was set up through the interactive RST interface you would hit before booting.  That same interface indicated that two of my four drives were experiencing issues.

Ultimately, I had to replace the two faulty drives.

That said, to get some of my data back, I disabled S.M.A.R.T. temporarily in my BIOS.  the RST interface no longer recognized my drives as failing, and allowed me to access the data in Windows.

Since the drives were failing, I didn't have long to pull the data off of the array, so if this is your issue i would only attempt it after confirming that you have a target disk to move your data onto.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. We’re your drives also indicated as no longer in the raid, by the RST software? Mine don’t show as failing, simple not members of the raid, so I’m not sure if the SMART status is what’s keeping Winslows from letting me at them.